# Probability that a randomly selected integer $n\ge0$ is divisible by $p>0$ tends to $1/p$ for large $n$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, notation

I am looking for a proof verification for the question in the title: Probability that a randomly selected integer $n\ge0$ is divisible by $p>0$ tends to $1/p$ for large $n$. I want to get the wording and notation accurate and precise as possible so any comments or suggestions are appreciated. (I believe we assume $p\in\mathbb{N}$). My attempt is below.

For $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$ we can write $n=p\cdot m+r$ for $p\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m,r\in\mathbb{N_0}$. Here $m$ is the number of integers less than $n$, which is also divisible by $n$, and $r$ is the remainder $0\le r\le p-1$. Then the probability is given by $$P(n\text{ is divisible by }p)=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-r}{p}=\frac{1}{p}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)$$
which tends to $1/p$ for fixed $r$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: In general, if you fix $p$ as a positive integer and define $f(n)$ as the number of integers in the set $\{1, ..., n\}$ that are divisible by $p$, then you likely want to show $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = 1/p$$ This  is one way to use the word "random integer" that is of course not using probability theory. Here we are just talking about the fraction of occurrences within the natural numbers (not using any probability measure). You may want to use your $m$ and $n$ arguments here for this, but I found your formulation unclear.

Comment: @Michael. What can I do to make it more clear? I essentially followed steps in my module, except the example given was with $p=7$.

Comment: Your sentence "Here $m$ is the number of integers less than $n$, which is also divisible by $n$" is unclear, likely has a typo, likely should emphasize you are only concerned with positive integers (although if $n$ is a positive integer, there are no positive integers less than $n$ that are also divisible by $n$).  In my comment I defined $f(n)$ as a clear function of $n$ and defined my method of evaluating by taking a limit, without calling it a probability. If $m$ is a real number then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{m}{n}=0$ and so you can use notation $m_n$ or $m(n)$. I used $f(n)$.